# Open SWF in Chrome for Android

Tags: chrome-for-android, adobe-flash

I can open SWF URLs in Chrome for PC, however, I cannot open them using Chrome for Android on my device.

Is there a Chrome plugin, or is there Java code that will do the mission, if there is, I will create a new Android project and program it then install the APK.

**The URL that I test with is :**

http://www.b7r11.com/tkber.swf

Comment: Chrome for Android doesn't support Flash, and neither do newer Android versions.

Comment: Chrome for Android doesn't support extensions, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's your Android version? I'll assume you're using 4.1 or newer.

The .swf extension is used by files played by Adobe Flash Player. Unfortunately, Flash **is not supported on Android** since 4.1.

You can try installing the [Flash Player APK](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html). The latest version is for 4.0/ICS, but some people say it works on 4.1+/JB as well. Remember: **Your Mileage May Vary**™.

Additionally, Chrome for Android never supported Flash - even with the APK installed. (Thanks to Compro01 for confirming that!) So **you'll need to use a different browser**.

If you are *not* using Android 4.1 or newer, please update your question with more information.

Comment: Chrome Android doesn't play ball with flash.  You need to use a different browser to make use of the installed flash APK, which does work on at least 4.1 on my GS3.

Comment: @Compro01, thanks! That's what I suspected, and it's good to have confirmation. I've edited the answer with regard to your comment.

Comment: Furthermore, I'd recommend getting the apk [directly from Adobe](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html) rather than some random source.  I edited your answer to point there.

Comment: Many thanks. I probably shouldn't have just dropped in the first result from Google.

Answer (score -1):

Just downloaded [Flashfox from Google Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.browser.flashfox) and issues with swf dissapeared.